# Fill internal holes and merge faces

Tags: python

I have a number of planar objects with internal holes in them that I need to fill and clean up. This is rather easy to do manually. In edit mode I select the internal vertices and merge them at center, disolve internal vertices and finally uses f to clean up the surfaces. Also shift+f and alt+f helps a lot. I would now need a button in oject mode that does this for me to save time and wonder if you have any suggestion how to identify the internal vertices or some other method?
[image: Original object]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether it works "always" but you might give geometry nodes a try:

i could delete my "simple" holes with this setup:

[image]

[image]

hint: for gn pros here: it might be much better to use attribute statistic node for every mesh island and delete the mesh with island island with the most points (which should hopefully be the "outer mesh") which isn't safe always but more safe than my way ;)...and i have no idea how to realize that without loops.

Comment: Thanks, I have no experiannce using sverchok in a plugin. Would it be possible to connect this to a button and hide it from users?

Comment: I don’t understand your comment? What has Sverchok to do with this?

Comment: Sorry, still new at Blender and I have only used python scripting to code. I thought sverchok and geometry nodes was the same thing. I guess the question sould be, can I call these geometry nodes from a button and hide it from the users?

Comment: Ähm….sorry, I don’t know. But should be possible, yes. But I don’t know how to do it.